# C# Json Generic "Tiered" Deserialize

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON file into a generic stack of serialized objects so I can easily make a sort of tree view using a for loop.

I've done a little Googling over the past couple hours but can't seem to find anything that would allow a truly generic approach, as all seem to require using pre-declared variables, setting the max depth of the tree.

There are many online generic JSON viewers (though no code is provided) so I am sure this is possible, I just have no idea how.

The file I'm currently working with as an example is below, as is an example of how I'm trying to get this structured.

`{"arcanePrefs":[{"name":"playerWalkingSpeed","category":"player","value":"6"},{"name":"playerRunningSpeed","category":"player","value":"8"},{"name":"playerLookSpeed","category":"player","value":"12"},{"name":"playerHorTurnSpeed","category":"player","value":"2"},{"name":"playerVerTurnSpeed","category":"player","value":"2"},{"name":"playerJumpHeight","category":"player","value":"6"},{"name":"playerVertLimit","category":"player","value":"80"},{"name":"playerAirCtrl","category":"player","value":"True"},{"name":"playerGravMod","category":"player","value":"1.5"},{"name":"playerHBobWlkSpd","category":"player","value":"0.18"},{"name":"playerHBobRunSpd","category":"player","value":"0.35"},{"name":"playerHBobHgt","category":"player","value":"0.4"},{"name":"playerHCant","category":"player","value":"True"},{"name":"playerReloadSpeed","category":"player","value":"1"},{"name":"playerUseRadius","category":"player","value":"0.5"},{"name":"playerWasteHealth","category":"player","value":"False"},{"name":"playerWasteArmor","category":"player","value":"False"},{"name":"playerWasteAmmo","category":"player","value":"False"},{"name":"playerHeight","category":"player","value":"1.6"},{"name":"playerBaseHealth","category":"player","value":"100"},{"name":"playerMaxHealth","category":"player","value":"250"},{"name":"playerbaseArmor","category":"player","value":"100"},{"name":"playerMaxArmor","category":"player","value":"150"},{"name":"playerWeaponSoftDrag","category":"player","value":"True"},{"name":"enemyStunLock","category":"enemy","value":"True"},{"name":"enemyGunshotDetectRaduis","category":"enemy","value":"40"},{"name":"worldWaterFallDmg","category":"world","value":"False"},{"name":"worldCanShootSwitches","category":"world","value":"True"},{"name":"worldLavaDamagePerFrame","category":"world","value":"1"},{"name":"cameraFOV","category":"camera","value":"80"},{"name":"cameraToneMapping","category":"camera","value":"True"},{"name":"cameraCustomPixel","category":"camera","value":"True"},{"name":"cameraPixelRes","category":"camera","value":"res360p"},{"name":"cameraDither","category":"camera","value":"True"},{"name":"cameraDitherStrength","category":"camera","value":"0.95"},{"name":"cameraBloom","category":"camera","value":"True"},{"name":"cameraBloomInt","category":"camera","value":"5"},{"name":"cameraUnderwaterCol1","category":"camera","value":"0.1921569;0.3921569;0.4509804;1"},{"name":"cameraUnderwaterCol2","category":"camera","value":"0.3137255;0.5882353;0.5882353;1"},{"name":"cameraUnderlavaCol1","category":"camera","value":"0.9019608;0.2313726;0;1"},{"name":"cameraUnderlavaCol2","category":"camera","value":"0.9019608;0.6666667;0.3529412;1"},{"name":"cameraCshrCol","category":"camera","value":"0.4901961;0.4901961;0.4901961;1"},{"name":"cameraCshrTgtCol","category":"camera","value":"0.7803922;0;0;1"},{"name":"arcaneLimitFPS","category":"engine","value":"True"},{"name":"arcaneFpsLimit","category":"engine","value":"-1"},{"name":"engineUIScale","category":"engine","value":"0.7"},{"name":"srcBHopping","category":"sem","value":"False"}],"arcaneControls":[{"name":"contForward","key":119},{"name":"contLeft","key":97},{"name":"contBackward","key":115},{"name":"contRight","key":100},{"name":"contRotLeft","key":113},{"name":"contRotRight","key":101},{"name":"contJump","key":32},{"name":"contLookUp","key":280},{"name":"contLookDown","key":281},{"name":"contSprintHold","key":304},{"name":"contSprintToggle","key":301},{"name":"contCrouchHold","key":306},{"name":"contCrouchToggle","key":99},{"name":"contComFire","key":323},{"name":"contComFireAlt","key":305},{"name":"contComSFire","key":324},{"name":"contComSFireAlt","key":303},{"name":"contComReload","key":114},{"name":"contComPrevWeap","key":326},{"name":"contComNextWeap","key":327},{"name":"contComInspectWeap","key":103},{"name":"contDebug","key":96}]}`

[What I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkbhG.png)

Comment: Do not use links and/or images for what you're attempting to achieve. Links can go dead and the question (and therefor answer) will be no resource for the future

Comment: Sorry, that's just what it did when I went to upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Unity, but they seem to provide newtonsoft which is a powerfull serializer / deserializer library for json [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0/manual/index.html)

For your use case, you want to convert json to a list of objet I think, so deserialize in this case.

To obtain an object representation of your json string you can go like

```
string json; // you data here
Arcane arcane=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Arcane>(json);

public class Arcane
{
     public List<ArcanePref> arcanePrefs { get; set; }
     public List<ArcaneControl> arcaneControls { get; set; }
}
public class ArcanePref
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
public class ArcaneControl
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int key{ get; set; }
}
```

With the arcane object you can then access the acranePrefs and arcaneControls list.

To represent the json data in a tree view fashion with Unity, I found the [tree view api](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/2019.4/Manual/TreeViewAPI.html)
Which seem the most straight foward way to go for a tree view representation

Once you have your objects, it should be more or less simple.

Concerning riffnl comment, I do not have any idea what the end goal is, or what is the source you are using ^^'

Hope it helps !

Comment: I was hoping for a generic solution (something I can throw any json file into) so declaring the serialized classes and variables isn't really an option.
I've already managed to make a very specialised script for pulling all this apart, I was hoping for something a little more robust when handling other files.